# Jquery Save Documents onchange and Avoid Duplication of Documents

Tags: php, jquery

I am saving documents with onchange function in jquery. I am facing issue that when i save first document it save as single but when i save second document saveDocument function save first document again with second document.

```
`function saveDocument() {
// Get files
var data = {};
var files_to_upload = {};
var formData = new FormData();

var lead_id = $("#lead-id").val();

formData.append('lead_id', lead_id); 

Color_Copy_of_Id = document.getElementById('Color_Copy_of_Id').files;
Color_Copy_of_Id_back = document.getElementById('Color_Copy_of_Id_back').files;
SSN_Card = document.getElementById('SSN_Card').files;
Utility = document.getElementById('Utility').files;
Business_Voided_Check = document.getElementById('Business_Voided_Check').files;
Personal_Financial_Statment = document.getElementById('Personal_Financial_Statment').files;
Employed = document.getElementById('Employed').files;
Self_Employed = document.getElementById('Self_Employed').files;
// for (i = 0; i < files.length; i++){

    /** Only PDF files Allowed */
    // files_to_upload[] = files[i];
    formData.append('files[Color_Copy_of_Id]', Color_Copy_of_Id[0]);
    formData.append('files[Color_Copy_of_Id_back]', Color_Copy_of_Id_back[0]);
    formData.append('files[SSN_Card]', SSN_Card[0]);
    formData.append('files[Utility]', Utility[0]);
    formData.append('files[Business_Voided_Check]', Business_Voided_Check[0]);
    formData.append('files[Personal_Financial_Statment]', Personal_Financial_Statment[0]);
    formData.append('files[Employed]', Employed[0]);
    formData.append('files[Self_Employed]', Self_Employed[0]);

// }

if($("[id='Signed Loan Application']").length > 0){
    Signed_Loan_Application = document.getElementById('Signed Loan Application').files;
    formData.append('files[Signed loan Application]', Signed_Loan_Application[0]);
}
if($("[id='2019 Business Tax Returns']").length > 0){
    Business_Tax_Returns_2019 =  document.getElementById('2019 Business Tax Returns').files;
    formData.append('files[2019 Business Tax Returns]', Business_Tax_Returns_2019[0]);
}
if($("[id='2020 Business Tax Returns']").length > 0){

    Business_Tax_Returns_2020 =  document.getElementById('2020 Business Tax Returns').files;
    formData.append('files[2020 Business Tax Returns]', Business_Tax_Returns_2020   [0]);
}
if($("[id='2021 Business Tax Returns']").length > 0){
    Business_Tax_Returns_2021 =  document.getElementById('2021 Business Tax Returns').files;
    formData.append('files[2021 Business Tax Returns]', Business_Tax_Returns_2021[0]);
}
if($("[id='2019 Personal Tax Returns']").length > 0){
    Personal_Tax_Returns_2019 =  document.getElementById('2019 Personal Tax Returns').files;
    formData.append('files[2019 Personal Tax Returns]', Personal_Tax_Returns_2019[0]);
}
if($("[id='2020 Personal Tax Returns']").length > 0){
    Personal_Tax_Returns_2020 =  document.getElementById('2020 Personal Tax Returns').files;
    formData.append('files[2020 Personal Tax Returns]', Personal_Tax_Returns_2020[0]);
}
if($("[id='2021 Personal Tax Returns']").length > 0){
    Personal_Tax_Returns_2021 =  document.getElementById('2021 Personal Tax Returns').files; 
    formData.append('files[2021 Personal Tax Returns]', Personal_Tax_Returns_2021[0]);
}
if($("[id='YTD Profit and Loss Statement']").length > 0){
    Balance_Sheet_YTD_PF =  document.getElementById('YTD Profit and Loss Statement').files;
    formData.append('files[YTD Profit and Loss Statement]', Balance_Sheet_YTD_PF[0]); 
}
if($("[id='Business Debt Schedule']").length > 0){
    Business_Debt_Schedule =  document.getElementById('Business Debt Schedule').files;
    formData.append('files[Business Debt Schedule]', Business_Debt_Schedule[0]);
}
if($("[id='Personal Financial Statement']").length > 0){
    Personal_Financial_Statement_G =  document.getElementById('Personal Financial Statement').files;
    formData.append('files[Personal Financial Statement]', Personal_Financial_Statement_G[0]);
}
if($("[id='4 Months Business Bank Statements']").length > 0){
    Four_Months_Business_Bank_Statements =  document.getElementById('4 Months Business Bank Statements').files;
    formData.append('files[4 Months Business Bank Statements]', Four_Months_Business_Bank_Statements[0]);
}
if($("[id='Personal_Voided_Check']").length > 0){
    Personal_Voided_Check =  document.getElementById('Personal_Voided_Check').files; 
    formData.append('files[Personal_Voided_Check]', Personal_Voided_Check[0]);
}
if($("[id='YTD_Balance_Sheet_Statement']").length > 0){
    YTD_Balance_Sheet_Statement =  document.getElementById('YTD_Balance_Sheet_Statement').files; 
    formData.append('files[YTD_Balance_Sheet_Statement]', YTD_Balance_Sheet_Statement[0]);
}
if($("[id='SS4_IRSEIN_Letter']").length > 0){
    SS4_IRSEIN_Letter =  document.getElementById('SS4_IRSEIN_Letter').files; 
    formData.append('files[SS4_IRSEIN_Letter]', SS4_IRSEIN_Letter[0]);
}
if($("[id='other']").length > 0){
    other =  document.getElementById('other').files;
    formData.append('files[other]', other[0]);
}

$.ajax({
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-Token': _token
    },
    data: formData,
    type: "POST",
    url: base_url + "Leads/saveDocument",
    success: function (response) {
        console.log("SUCCESS");
        var result = JSON.parse(response);
        var docu_ids = result['document_id'];
        
        $(document).on('change', '.docs_field', function ()  { 
            console.log("check");
            $(this).next('.doc_hidden_id').val(docu_ids);
        });

    }
});
```

}`

Data is sending to php function using above code. The php function code id

```
`function saveDocument(){
 
    Log::write('debug', 'Save document');

    $restAPI = new RestAPIHelper(new \Cake\View\View());
    if ($this->request->is('Ajax')) {
        $this->autoRender = false;
        $data = $this->request->getData();

        $field_mapping_arr = array(
            "Color_Copy_of_Id" => "sales_check_color_copy_id_c",
            "Color_Copy_of_Id_back" => "sales_check_color_copy_id_back_c",
            "SSN_Card" => "sales_check_ssn_card_c",
            "Utility" => "sales_check_utility_bill_c",
            "Personal_Voided_Check" => "sales_check_ach_voided_check_c",
            "Business_Voided_Check" => "sales_check_business_voided_check_c",
            "Personal_Financial_Statment" => "sales_check_financial_statement_c",
            "Employed" => "sales_check_employed_c",
            "Remove Fraud Alerts" => "sales_check_remove_fraud_alerts_c",
            "Self_Employed" => "sales_check_self_employed_c",
            "Business Debt Schedule" => "sales_check_debt_schedule_c",
            "Signed loan Application" => "sales_check_signed_application_c",
            "YTD Profit and Loss Statement" => "sales_check_ytd_balance_sheet_c",
            "YTD_Balance_Sheet_Statement" => "sales_check_ytd_balance_sheet_statement_c",
            "SS4_IRSEIN_Letter" => "sales_check_ss4_irsein_letter_c",
        );

        Log::write('debug', "SaveDocument");
        Log::write('debug', $data);

        $files_arr = $data["files"];

        foreach($files_arr as $document_type => $doc_arr){
            Log::write('debug', "doc_arr");
            Log::write('debug', $doc_arr);
            if($doc_arr != 'undefined')
            {

            
                $dataToSave = array (
                    'lead_id' => $data["lead_id"],
                    'document_name' => $doc_arr["name"],
                    'document_type' => str_replace("_"," ",$document_type),
                    'template_type' => str_replace("_"," ",$document_type),
                    'revision' => '1'

                );
                $sendResult = $restAPI->setRecord('Documents', $dataToSave);
                Log::write("debug", "dataToSave");
                Log::write("debug", $dataToSave);
                $dataToSaveForLead = array (
                    'id' => $data["lead_id"],
                    "$field_mapping_arr[$document_type]" => true,
                );

                Log::write("debug", "dataToSaveForLead");
                Log::write("debug", $dataToSaveForLead);

                Log::write("debug", "sendResult->id");
                Log::write("debug", $sendResult->id);
                $docu_details = array(
                    'document_id' => $sendResult->id,
                );
                $sendResultLead = $restAPI->setRecord('Leads', $dataToSaveForLead);

                if($sendResult->id){
                    $param = array (
                        'note' => array(
                            //The ID of the parent document.
                            'id' => $sendResult->id,

                            //The binary contents of the file.
                            'file' => base64_encode(file_get_contents($doc_arr['tmp_name'])),

                            //The name of the file
                            'filename' => $doc_arr['name'],

                            //The revision number
                            'revision' => '1',
                        ),
                    );
                    $result = $restAPI->createDocumentRevision($param);
                }
            }
        }

        ob_clean();
        Log::write("debug", "DATA");
        Log::write("debug", $docu_details);
        echo json_encode($docu_details);
        exit;
        
    }
    
}`
```

And onchange function is

```
`$(document).on('change', '.docs_field', function ()  { 
        if (this.files[0].size > 20971520) {
            swal("Please select file less then 20MB");
        $(this).val('');
    }
    else
    {
       saveDocument();
    }
});`
```

All input type fields have same class docs field.

I want that function should save the document of active input field.
I apologies if i am asking non sense query.

Comment: Please provide a proper [mre] of the issue. Show us what the form actually looks like. I can't currently tell how you expect this to work - you are appending a handful of files in any case, and then the rest is dependent on whether elements with certain IDs are found. But won't the latter always be the case? Are you removing those elements somewhere in between, or what?

Comment: Your code just goes through all the files in the input each time a single one is added, so it'll re-upload anything still selected. And also when the ajax completes it seems to add another "change" handler even though there is already one declared, so that would end up running the whole routine multiple times in parallel each time something is changed too. Sit down with the code and have a really good rethink about the logic. It's written like there should be one big upload of files at once, but handled as if one file will be added at a time.